# MS Access VBA interpreting string from SQL as int?

Tags: sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that returns a varchar value to Access VBA, but I'm getting an error from Access saying it can't convert a varchar value to int. Nowhere is the return value specified as an integer, whether the procedure or in VBA.  I've simplified the actual code for the sake of this post. The below is not the full code.

### Stored procedure:

```
create procedure proc 
@CreateOrUpdate varchar(6) output
as
begin
select @CreateOrUpdate = 'Create'
return @CreateOrUpdate
end
```

### In Access VBA:

```
Dim Com As ADODB.Command
Set Com = New ADODB.Command
With Com
    .ActiveConnection = Cnn  (Set elsewhere - No problems with this)
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "proc"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@CreateOrUpdate", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 6)
End With
```

Result:
"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Create' to data type int."

I have other return values that are also varchar with identical syntax and I'm not having any problems with them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"I have other return values that are also varchar with identical syntax and I'm not having any problems with them"* I doubt this, unless they can be implicitly cast to an `int`; and then you have other problems.

Comment: If you have "other return values that are also varchar", those will only work coincidentally if they're always convertible to an integer (including `NULL` values and empty strings/whitespace -- these will end up as 0). You should definitely remove these if they're used in `RETURN` statements. You can have any number of `VARCHAR` output parameters, though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your attempt to use `RETURN` to return a value for an `OUTPUT` parameter. `RETURN` is used to denote the success of a Procedure; `0` for success and anything else for failure. `RETURN`  returns an **`int`**, so `RETURN @CreateOrUpdate` will implicitly try convert `@CreateOrUpdate` to an `int` (hence the failure).

Don't `RETURN` the `OUTPUT` value, just assign it:

```sql
CREATE PROC MyProc @CreateOrUpdate varchar(6) OUTPUT AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @CreateOrUpdate = 'Create';
END;
```

*Though the above it completely pointless. What is it trying to achieve..?*

Comment: See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64754312/ms-access-vba-interpreting-string-from-sql-as-int/64754351?noredirect=1#comment114491796_64754312) under your question, @BellaFiorenza .